# Google Apps Script Directory API to Write ALL User fields to a Google Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Trying to write all users.organizations.name (title, primary, type, customType, etc) via GAS Directory API to a Google Sheet. Script below separates fullName, primaryEmail, & id into separate columns but writes organizations into a single column. I'd like to spilt organizations values up into separate columns.

```js
function getAllUsers2(){
  var values = [],
      users = [],
      userListQuery = {},
      nextPageToken = '',
      listObject = {
          domain:'hhs1.com',
          maxResults: 500,
          projection: 'full',
          customerId: 'my_customer'
      },
      i = 0;

  do {

    if (nextPageToken && nextPageToken !== '') {
      listObject.pageToken = nextPageToken;
    }  

    userListQuery = AdminDirectory.Users.list(listObject);

    // if there are more users than fit in the query a nextPageToken is returned
    nextPageToken = userListQuery.nextPageToken;

    // Add the query results to the users array
    users = users.concat(userListQuery.users);

  } while (nextPageToken);

  for (i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {      
    
    values.push([users[i].name.fullName,
                 users[i].primaryEmail,
                 users[i].id,
                 users[i].organizations]);
  
  }

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetName = 'USERS2';
  var header = ["Name", "Email","ID","Organizations"]
  sheetExists(sheetName);
  
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, header.length).setValues([header]); //Note: I had to add brackets around header for this to work. Was getting "Cannot convert Array to Object[][]" before I did so
  sheet.getRange(2, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
  Logger.log(values);
}
```

Here's what is added in column D after running:
[partial product from script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTl1x.png)

Here is part of the USERS JSON Template for reference:

```js
"organizations": [
    {
      "name": string,
      "title": string,
      "primary": boolean,
      "type": string,
      "customType": string,
      "department": string,
      "symbol": string,
      "location": string,
      "description": string,
      "domain": string,
      "costCenter": string
    }
  ],
```

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  We are a question-and-answer site, not a coders-for-hire service. Please explain what you have tried so far and why it hasn't worked.  See: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Ok, fair point. Thanks for the feedback. My specific question is: how do I get this information:  "organizations": [
  {
   "name": "value here",
   "title": "value here",
   "primary": true,
   "customType": "",
   "department": "value here"
  }
 ], added as individual columns on a google sheet via Google Apps Script? Current script "users[i].organizations" dumps this info into a single column.

Comment: Can you please edit your question rather than putting that in a comment?  Many will miss it there.

Comment: Will do - thank you!